# Find a triplet with sum=0 in a BST - Time complexity with below code

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I wrote the below code for finding a Triplet in a BST that adds upto 0. But having difficulty determining the time complexity.

The find() method's time complexity is O(logn). Is the time time complexity of isTriplet() O(n^2) ?

```
bool find(Node* root, int target) {
  if (root == NULL)
      return false;

  if (root->data == target)
      return true;

  return (target < root->data) ?  find(root->left, target) :  find(root->right, target);
}

bool isTriplet(Node* root, Node* actualRoot) {
  if (root == NULL)
     return false;

  if (root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL)
      return false;

  int sum = root->data;
  if (root->left)
      sum += root->left->data;
  else if (root->right)
      sum += root->right->data;

  sum = -1 * sum;

  return (find(actualRoot, sum) || isTriplet(root->left, actualRoot) || isTriplet(root->right, actualRoot));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A triplet with sum = 0 means a node, a left and a right child having the sum of the three elements equals to 0.

Let's think logically. Where should we search for such triplets starting from the root of the tree? Basically, if the root is a positive, then to the left and if the root is a negative, then to the right.

When should we check whether such a triplet is found? In the case when there is at least a negative and at least a positive among the three numbers. 0 is a special case, I will deal with it separately.

If such a sum is found, then we should return it and should stop the algorithm. So, if the node is not 0 and there is no triplet, then we know which sub-tree to search in. If it is a triplet, then we have a trivial case, since the solution is found. If the current node is 0, then we should check whether its triplet is 0. If it is not, then we can stop the search, as no sub-tree will contain positives and negatives. The exception, off course is when the current node is 0 and exactly one of its children is also 0. In that case we need to check that subtree as well.

The algorithm should have a base 2 logarithmical complexity for worst-case scenario. Proof:

1. When such a triplet is found, the algorithm should stop.
2. If no such triplet is found yet and the current node is not 0, then we have an interesting and a non-interesting subtree.
3. If no such triplet is found yet and the current node is 0, then either:

3.1. Both its children are 0 and we have found such a triplet,

3.2. None of its children are 0 and therefore it is provable that no such triplet exists, or

3.3. One of its children is 0 but the other is not, in which case the 0 child defines the interesting subtree and the other child deinfes the non-interesting subtree.

Since all the cases are either trivially stopping the algorithm due to the existence or inexistence of a solution, or halve the tree into interesting and non-interesting subtrees, the algorithm traverses a single node the most on each level and therefore its complexity in worst case equals the height of the tree, which is binary logarithmical.